# Two Google Drive accounts

Tags: macos, google-apps

I am trying to enable two Google Drive accounts (private and work) following [these steps](https://plus.google.com/+JoshEstelle/posts/1mYzdE5KKgv). In addition, I did chown to my main account (user), and chmod appropriately. However, it seems to me that the second account is not synced until I actually switch to that second user. Anyone with similar experience? Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

(A) [This one](http://blog.myitcv.org.uk/2015/03/28/connect-multiple-google-drive-accounts-to-one-mac-os-x-user.html) (Being a few terminal commands you can run)

OR

(B) Buying this app called [Insynchq](https://www.insynchq.com/) for $25/yr (15 day trial avail.)

Comment: Any thoughts about ExpanDrive and CyberDuck? I know they deal with the issue differently but offer comparable results so to say.